# Selection of Distribution model

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

An expressed parcel delivery company offers a First Class service for which it is promised that 80% of all parcels are delivered within 24 hours of dispatch. It is suspected that the true successful next-day delivery rate might be somewhat lower. To measure performance against this claim of 80%, a random sample of recent First Class deliveries are inspected one after another. A delivery which has not been made within 24 hours of dispatch can be classified as late. The performance of each of these deliveries can be assumed to be independent of one another.

Let X be a random variable denoting the number of deliveries examined by the inspector until discovering one which was late. State the distribution of X if 80% of all parcels are indeed delivered on time.

The answer is Geometric Distribution. However, I don't understand why it couldn't be modelled by Poisson Distribution.

What is the general rule of thumb in selecting the correct distribution model, I somehow never able to choose the correct one.
Cheers.

Comment: It is comprehensible for you, that it is the geometric distribution. If yes, then it cannot be the poisson distribution. The poisson distribution is a special case of the binomial distribution. In the exercise there cannot be more than one late delivery of the inspected deliveries.. And this late delivery is always discovered at the end. Thus it cannot be the binominal distribution and it cannot be the poisson distribution.

Answer (score 0):

From the problem:

> Let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of deliveries examined by the inspector until discovering one which was late.

This should immediately jump out as a geometric distribution. It is the number of trials until a success. A Poisson distribution would be used if the quantity of interest were the number of successes.